# JPA/HIBERNATE doesn't retrieve correctly entity after its own save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi i have straightforward problem,

i want insert new record in table and after this, retrieve this new record with all relationship (list attached ecc..).

[image]

In the insertion phase I have some object like WvClsProgetto with only ID into it, to allow Hibernate to correctly insert the foreign keys, 
so these objects do not have additional information but only ID.

When i save my entity i want retrieve it, but when i retrieve my entity my VwClsProgetto inside of it is fill with only ID ... and not with all its properties :

[image]

But this properties are all null, obviously record in my table have this properties properly valued.

I do save in this way :

[image]

MY REPOSITORY CLASS IS:

[image]

BASE REPOSITORY IS FROM JPA :

[image]

POM SNIPPET :

[image]

HELP ME!

Comment: You are misunderstanding some fundamentals here. If `scheda` is new then your initial scheda instance and the the `scheda` instance returned by the save operation are **the same objects in memory**. If you want to force a database reload then you'd need to refresh it or clear the persistence context and then query for it. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to cascade the save, otherwise only the root entity will get saved:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private WvClsProgetto wvClsProgetto;
```

**Update**

In order to save an entity with an already existing dependency, you have to retrieve it first, so that it is in the persistence context.

```
VwClsProgetto existingVwClsProgetto = vwClsProgettoRepository.findById(
     scheda.getVwClsProgetto().getId())
   .get()
```

then re-set that property:

```
scheda.setVwClsProgetto(existingVwClsProgetto);
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the issue. As I understand it, he would not place a "dummy VwClsProgetto" on the `Scheda`, but the actual entity retrieved from database. To me it sounds like `VwClsProgetto` already exists in the database. Also the transactions come into play here. He saves and retrieves within the same transaction. It should be 2 transactions

Comment: If its the same transaction, the entities should be retrieved from the persistence context in that case

Comment: I correctly saved my entity, when i try to retrieve it, VwClsProgetto have only ID inside of it, like when i saved my entity, i want full filled VwClsProgetto in my entity when i retrieve it.

Comment: You have to retrieve the VwClsProgetto first so that it is in the persistence context. Then you set that property on the Scheda entity and perform the save

Comment: Either way, your answer doesn't solve the problem at hand